# Error Setting Validations to textFields

Tags: ios, validation, uitextfield

With Following code i am trying to validate the email textFields but the problem is that even if the Email and Confirm email text in both the text field is same it gives error message that they are not same. Don't know whats wrong with my code.Any help?

```
 - (IBAction)submit_Act:(id)sender {
 //new//
 NSString  *errorMessage;
 errorMessage = @"";
if ([usernametxt.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    errorMessage = @"Please enter Username \n";
}

if([passwordtxt.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter Password\n"];
}

if([confirmPasswordtxt.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter Confirm Password\n"];
}
if((passwordtxt.text == confirmPasswordtxt.text) == false){
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Password and Confirm Password are not same.\n"];
}

NSString *regex = @"[^@]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]+";
NSPredicate *emailPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES  %@", regex];

if([emailaddtxt.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter Email Address\n"];
}
else if ([emailPredicate evaluateWithObject:emailaddtxt.text] == NO) {
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter valid Email Address\n"];
}

if([confirmEmailtxt.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter Confirm Email Address\n"];
}
else if ([emailPredicate evaluateWithObject:confirmEmailtxt.text] == NO) {
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter valid confirm Email Address\n"];
}

if((emailaddtxt.text == confirmEmailtxt.text) == false)
{
   errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Email and Confirm Email are not same.\n"];
}

if([citytxt.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter City\n"];
}

if([statetxt.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter State\n"];
}

if([countrytxt.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter Country\n"];
}

if (_agree_btn.selected==false) {
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please agree Terms & Conditions\n"];
}

if (![errorMessage isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSLog(@"not done");
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:errorMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] show];
    return;
 }
}   else{

    NSLog(@" Done Dana done");

    _activityIndicator.hidden=NO;
    [_activityIndicator startAnimating];

    protocolTest = [[ClassWithProtocol alloc] init];
    [protocolTest setDelegate:self];
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"task=webapi.registerClient&username=%@&password=%@&person_name=%@&email=%@&terms_check=1&city=%@&state=%@&country=%@&user_id=%@",usernametxt.text,passwordtxt.text,contactPersonstxt.text,emailaddtxt.text,citytxt.text,statetxt.text,countrytxt.text,_fetchid];
    [protocolTest  startLogintask:post];

}
```

Comment: do not compare string like "if((emailaddtxt.text == confirmEmailtxt.text) == false)" compare them like "if([emailaddtxt.text isEqualToString:: confirmEmailtxt.text])"

Comment: Any help guys, still having the same issue?

Comment: Do any one have idea about the problem i am facing here ?

Comment: @vicky Did you check the both(password and confirm password) values by printing in the console? there might be any reference issues...

Comment: @Bharath yes i have checked by printing in console also the values are right. But even if the email and confirm email are same it is giving me error that they are not same but working fine for password and confirm password

Comment: updated the full code

Comment: I made it, the problem here was the textFields having @ and . signs cannot be compared directly. We need to convert them in string first and the compare them using isEqualToString see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if((emailaddtxt.text == confirmEmailtxt.text) == false)
{
   errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Email and Confirm Email are not same.\n"];
}
```

compare them like

```
if(![emailaddtxt.text isEqualToString:confirmEmailtxt.text])
{
   errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Email and Confirm Email are not same.\n"];
}
```

Comment: and what if email and confirmEmail are same, still it will show that message

Comment: Prajapathi your updated answer is nothing but same as the answer given by Kirti Mali see below, the answer given by her .

Comment: oh sorry! but first time i forgot to put  "!" sign.

Comment: ok. But what about the issue it is working fine for password and confirm password but if email and confirm email are same it still shows message that they are not same. Is It due to we are checking it with regex ? where could be the issue

Comment: check for uppercase & lowercase string?

Comment: i think the problem is due to the way i am writing the code, is there is any other way to do this. i mean to write a certain method for regex and use it in button action.

Comment: I made it, the problem here was the textFields having @ and . signs cannot be compared directly. We need to convert them in string first and the compare them using isEqualToString see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
if([passwordtxt text] != [confirmPasswordtxt text])
{
     errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Password and Confirm Password are not same.\n"];
}
```

for email,

```
if([emailaddtxt text] != [confirmEmailtxt text])
{
     errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Email and Confirm Email are not same.\n"];
}
```

This will work good.

Comment: no its not working if both email and Confirm email are same, it gives error that email and confirm email are not same

Comment: have you try with `isEqualToString` ??

Comment: I made it, the problem here was the textFields having @ and . signs cannot be compared directly. We need to convert them in string first and the compare them using isEqualToString see the solution.

Comment: Yeah that's right...and i tried as given in my answer and its working at my end also. By d way its great that finally you got it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the support  :)

Answer (score 0):

Check below code:

```
if(![emailaddtxt.text isEqual:confirmEmailtxt.text])
{
   errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Email and Confirm Email are not same.\n"];
}
```

Comment: it is giving me the same error email and confEmail are not same even if they are same

Comment: @vicky my code replace with your this line code if((emailaddtxt.text == confirmEmailtxt.text) == false)

Comment: make sure don't forget " !"  in if condition

Comment: ya i have added that

Comment: I made it, the problem here was the textFields having @ and . signs cannot be compared directly. We need to convert them in string first and the compare them using isEqualToString see the solution.

Comment: @vicky no need to convert to string check my updated and tested  function
isEqual function check object so it worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was the textFields having @ and . signs cannot be compared directly. We need to convert them in string first and the compare them using isEqualToString so here i the solution i found on my problem.

```
 NSString *emailID = emailaddtxt.text;
 NSString *confemail = confirmEmailtxt.text;

 NSString *regex = @"[^@]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]+";
 NSPredicate *emailPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES  %@", regex];

if([emailID isEqualToString:@""]){
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter Email Address\n"];
    NSLog(@"email is%@",self.emailaddtxt);
 }

if ([emailPredicate evaluateWithObject:emailID] == NO) {
  errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter valid Email Address\n"];
 }


 NSString *regex2 = @"[^@]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]+";
 NSPredicate *confemailPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES  %@", regex2];

 if([confemail isEqualToString:@""]){
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter Confirm Email Address\n"];
    NSLog(@"email is%@",self.confirmEmailtxt.text);
 }

 if([confemailPredicate evaluateWithObject:confemail] == NO)
 {
    errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Please enter valid confirm Email Address\n"];
 }

 if(![emailID isEqualToString:confemail])
{
  errorMessage = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:@"Email and Confirm Email are not same.\n"];
  NSLog(@"email is%@& confemail is%@" ,self.emailaddtxt.text,self.confirmEmailtxt.text);
}
```